# Spring Security - Basic HTTP Authentication - change server message

Tags: spring, spring-security, http-authentication

If you are authenticating yourself with basic HTTP Authentication, you will see a popup like this: [image]

I want to change: The server says: `Spring Security Application` to something else. But I am not sure where to change this?

Comment: Where does this originate from? How do you set the user and pass?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Specify a realm.

Eg.

```
<http realm="My Owesome Web App">
```